# Covariance update from Jacobian of transition function

Tags: covariance, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, gradient-descent, particle-filter

In this [paper](http://www.jseepub.com/EN/article/downloadArticleFile.do?attachType=PDF&id=9027) on particle filtering with gradient descent, the authors sample *X*<sub>*k*+1</sub> through gradient descent, then update the covariance matrix P associated with *X*<sub>k+1</sub> as follows:

P<sup>i+1</sup><sub>(k + 1|k + 1)</sub> = P<sup>i</sup><sub>(k + 1|k)</sub>−
P<sup>i</sup><sub>(k + 1|k)</sub>[H<sup>i+1</sup><sub>x</sub><sub>(k + 1)</sub> P<sup>i</sup><sub>(k + 1|k)</sub> ·
(H<sup>i+1</sup><sub>x</sub><sub>(k + 1)</sub>)' +R<sub>(k + 1)</sub>] H<sup>i+1</sup><sub>x</sub><sub>(k + 1)</sub> P<sup>i</sup><sub>(k + 1|k)</sub>

where *H*<sup>*i*+1</sup><sub>*x*</sub><sub>(*k* + 1)</sub> = *h<sub>x</sub>*[*k* + 1, *x*<sup>*i*+1</sup>(*k* + 1)] 
and *h<sub>x</sub>* is the Jacobian matrix of transition function *h*(·).[Equns 13/14 of cited paper]

To paraphrase, I think they mean if *P* is the covariance of state *X* of dimensions (dimx,dimx), *R* is the covariance of the observed *Y* of dimensions (`dimy`, `dimy`), and *H* is the gradients of *Y* w/r/t *X* (at *x*), of dimensions (`dimy`, `dimx`) then 
  $P = P - P\cdot(H\cdot P\cdot H' +R)\cdot H\cdot P$

However, if I set `P = rand(5,5); R= rand(2,2); H = rand(2,5)`; I get an inner matrix multiplication dimensions error evaluating the above. My question is:

- is the "Jacobian matrix of transition function *h*" really the dh/dx matrix of dimensions (*y,x*) ?  If so how do I calculate this formula so the dimensions match?

  if not what is the correct interpretation, or if the formula is incorrect, how can I best calculate the posterior covariance for each particle?

Thank you!